# Converting from alpha to numeric with decimals fails

Tags: rpgle

I have to convert a alphanumeric value  to a numeric value with decimal places:

> Input: '6000'
>
> Output. 60.00

So I tried the `%dec()` BIF which takes the input as alpha, the precision and the decimal places. But when trying this:

```
dcl-s alphanumeric char(13);
dcl-s numeric packed(13:2);

alphanumeric = '6000';
numeric = %dec(alphanumeric:13:2);

*inlr = *on;
```

the conversion produces `NUMERIC = 00000006000.00` and not `NUMERIC = 000000060.00`. So what am I doing wrong?

Even when using `zoned(13:2)` instead of `packed(13:2)` the value doesn't have decimal places other than `'00'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to do get 60.00 is to multiply the result by .01.

```
numeric = %dec(alphanumeric:13:0) * .01;
```

The length and decimal places for %DEC aren't used to specify how to interpret the character value, they are just used to set the size of the result. If the character value is '6000', the result of %DEC is always 6000, but depending on the length and decimals of %DEC, it might be 006000.000, or 6000.00, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The only easy way i know is a mix from free with good old rpg-syntax:

```js
  EvalR VarText = '6000';
C                   Move      VarText       VarDec
```

With **move** you can easily transfer the **right adjusted** value into the numeric field

Comment: Yes, this code is only for rpgle without **FREE
It is not beautiful but it works :-)

Answer (score 2):

Just for completeness, you could use a data structure to do the conversion as well. But, the conversion is not as explicit when you do that.

```
**free
dcl-ds *n;
  charfld     char(6);
  numfld      zoned(6: 2) Pos(1);
end-ds;

evalr charfld = '6000';
dsply %char(numfld);
return;
```

> ```
>                       Display Program Messages                          
>
> Job 499369/XXXXXXX/QPADEV0011 started on 05/29/19 at 08:31:13 in subsystem Q
> DSPLY  60.00
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Alpha `6000` become `6000.00` in Numeric, it's correct.

If you want to interpret the last 2 digits like decimal, you must but a `.` into your string.

```
str = %subst(alphanumeric: 1: %len(alphanumeric)-3) + '.' + %subst(alphanumeric: %len(alphanumeric)-2: 2)
```

And then convert the new string into a number.

You can also use EMBEDDED SQL:

```
EXEC SQL 
SET :NEW_STRING = (
                    SELECT
                        DECIMAL( substr(:alphanumeric,   1,   LENGTH(:alphanumeric)-3) 
                        CONCAT '.' 
                        CONCAT substr(:alphanumeric, LENGTH(:alphanumeric)-2,  2), 
                        13, 2)
                    FROM
                        sysibm.sysdummy1 
                  )
```